# Mysql select query nut running at all

Tags: php, oracle, select-query

I have the following query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM so.KI WHERE ICCID IN ('$nabi') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

But I get the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

SELECT * FROM so.KI WHERE ICCID in 8993017100107912997,8993017100107913011,8993017100107913029,8993017100107913037,8993017100107913045
```

They `so` database is Oracle and the `KI` table has got 2700000 records.

any help is highly appreciated!
I wonder why such error is showed up!

Comment: numbers are also enclosed in a pair of parantheses!

Comment: $nabi is an array of ICCIDs coming from interface! I even wrote ICCIDs manually in the `IN()` section, but it is showing the same error!!

Answer (score 1):

here 8993017100107912997,8993017100107913011,8993017100107913029,8993017100107913037,8993017100107913045 is diffrent ids so as per you had defin

"SELECT * FROM so.KI WHERE ICCID IN ('$nabi') " its contain all string in condition.

please try below. and also check DATAbase connection also.

"SELECT * FROM so.KI WHERE ICCID IN ($nabi) "

Answer (score 1):

when using in('$variable') it prints as ('a,b.c.d') while it should be in('a','b','c','d')
you have to put quotation for each element inside in() clause